# How to set "unlimited" screen width for `ps` to prevent it from truncating output?

Tags: linux, debian, ps

`ps` truncates output when standard output is a terminal to accommodate the terminal's width.

I see from `ps --help output` that `ps` supports `--width` and `--lines` options for controlling the screen width and height, respectively.

I find it awkward to specify a big arbitrary number like `--width 1000`, so is there some value or option that sets "unlimited" screen width?

```
root@controlplane:~# apt list --installed procps
Listing... Done
procps/now 2:3.3.12-3ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,local]
```

Extra: Is it possible to use search patterns with `-C <cmd>` to prevent having to type the `cmd` verbatim?

**Example**

```
root@controlplane:~# ps -f -C kubelet 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      9231     1  0 08:20 ?        00:00:07 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/
root@controlplane:~# ps -f -C kubelet | cat
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      9231     1  0 08:20 ?        00:00:08 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Doubling the `-w` option sets unlimited width](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#OUTPUT_MODIFIERS):

```
ps -fww -C kubelet
```

`ps` itself doesn’t support pattern searches, but you can combine it with `pgrep`:

```
ps -fww -p $(pgrep -d, kubelet)
```

(This will produce an error if no processes match.)

Answer (score 1):

A more general way to get wide output is:

```
env COLUMNS=2048 ps
```

or, make the output of `ps` not be a terminal:

```
ps | cat
```

This is very close to a Useless Use of  `cat`.